# How to fix "Invalid regular expression" in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo

`E:\React-Native\reactnativeapp>npm start`

I passed this command for compile my project in VS code via NPM command but last time its gave me error.

```
> @ start E:\React-Native\reactnativeapp
> expo start


Starting project at E:\React-Native\reactnativeapp

Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002

Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)

error Invalid regular expression:
 /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1

Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-08T06_13_41_377Z-debug.log
```

Comment: downgrade the node to version 12.9   It will fix the issue. 

 Using expo-cli 3.3.0.

Comment: okk bro, but which node version should i install in my pc.I'm using windows 10.

Comment: install node version 12.9 with expo-cli 3.3.0.